# Jenkins : Disable "Remember me on this computer"

Tags: jenkins

In the login page of jenkins , how can i disable\delete the check box "Remember me on this computer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following the below steps I am able to remove "Remember Me" checkbox in the login page of jenkins

1. Go to Installed location of Jenkins\WEB-INF\lib
2. Copy the file "jenkins-core-1.480.jar" to different location(This is the jar file where "remember me" checkbox is available)
3. Open the command prompt and point to the the location where the file "jenkins-core-1.480.jar" was copied in Step2.
4. Run the below command , this command extracts the contents of the jar file.
      jar -xvf jenkins-core-1.480.jar
5. After Step4 , locate the file login.jelly (Jenkins\model\jenkins\login.jelly in this version) and comment the below content

   ```
         <tr>
           <td align="right"><input id="remember_me" type="checkbox" name="remember_me" /></td>
           <td><label for="remember_me">${%Remember me on this computer}</label></td>
         </tr>
   ```
6. Delete the file "jenkins-core-1.480.jar" and run the below command in the command prompt(This will create the jar file again)
      jar -cvf jenkins-core-1.480.jar *
7. Stop the jenkins service and replace the jar file created in step6 with Installed location of Jenkins\WEB-INF\lib\jenkins-core-1.480.jar
8. Start the Jenkins service and check.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. You may want to file a request with the Jenkins developers at:

http://issues.jenkins-ci.org